# How to center bootstrap tooltip text vertically?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I want to center vertically the text inside the bootstrap tooltip but i still have like 1px or 2px to the bottom. I tried to add this css but can't fix it :

```
.tooltip-inner { 
  text-align: center !important;
  justify-content: center !important;
  align-content: center !important;
  vertical-align:middle !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first margin 0 and padding 0 and box-sizing-borderbox
after that use a paret for your toltip and use displaye-flex and
align item center justyfi-content:cneter
and its done